# Extracting metadata from wav files

Tags: metadata, wav

I was curious if there is a way to extract metadata from wav files. For instance, can you get bpm, key, instrument, etc. from a .wav file on upload?

Comment: http://meta-extractor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: WAV files or any audio format have no meta-data of the sort you asked. MIDI files have all those things you want but technically they aren't audio files.

Comment: So if I am running a site where users upload/download samples in the form of .wav files, what is the best way to get metadata from these samples? Will the users have to tag each individual samples that they upload with all of the relevant metadata? There has to be an easier and more automated way.

Comment: https://wavmetadata.blogspot.com/ This is a nice guide to start with and also lists some software that can edit it. Again, what you mentioned is typical of MIDI file *only*.

Comment: Im with @GabrielaGarcia on that, parameters: bpm, key, instrument applied to [MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI#Composition) files only. If your site is PHP based, there is IMHO a [good library](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3) for metadata extraction from audio/video files

Comment: its python based.

Comment: Regardless of the way it will be extracted, keep in mind that no method/tool can extract what isn't there. So, your users will have to edit in some way. I think it's doable with ID3 tagging as it allows several editable fields. That said, also important to understand is that ID3 is mostly used for meta-data like Artist, Album, Song Title, Year, barcode, etc. And that any info manually edited can be anything, it may not match the actual content and there's no software that can check for accuracy.

Comment: Interesting. If you reference Splice.com you will see that they have metadata attached to .wav samples with tags like genre, instrument, bpm, and key. I would find it hard to believe that users are inputting all of these variables on each upload, but I don't know.

Comment: https://splice.com/blog/mastering-101-preperation/ Quoting: *you may be required to submit ISRC Codes / Metadata (Artists information, Album titles, Track titles) to an aggregator. **There’s no easy way to do this but to type it out and double check to make sure that there are no mistakes.*** This is exactly what we've been telling you.